# Catch this.id inside for loop (JS)

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<button class="button" id="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button" id="2">Button 2</button>
```

JS

```
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

function chooseButton() {
    // works
    let buttonId = this.id;
    console.log('You choose button' + buttonId);
};

// Check for button click
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', chooseButton, false);
}
```

How do i listen for buttonId, catch it and use it outside the function?

```
if (buttonId == 1) {
   // do this
}
```

Comment: Where outside the function? Your question makes it look like you just have an `if` statement immediately after the event listener is added … so it will never match because the `if` statement will run before the user can click on anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the buttonId variable outside the function:

```js
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
let buttonId;
function chooseButton() {
    buttonId = this.id
    console.log('You choose button' + buttonId);
    checkerFunction();
};
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', chooseButton, false);
}

function checkerFunction()
{
  if (buttonId == 1)
  {
  console.log('TEST :: You choose button' + buttonId);
  }
  else
  {
  console.log('TEST :: You choose the other button' + buttonId);
  }

}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button" id="2">Button 2</button>
```

To verify that the value is readable we call the checkerFunction just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `let` inside function, if you want to access it outside. Should be

```
let  buttonId;
function chooseButton() {
    // works
    buttonId = this.id;
    console.log('You choose button' + buttonId);
};
```